# Why does Java automatically decode %2F in URI encoded filenames?

Tags: java, file, encoding, uri

I have a servlet that needs to write out files that have a user-configurable name.  I am trying to use URI encoding to properly escape special characters, but the JRE appears to automatically convert encoded forward slashes `%2F` into path separators.

Example:

```
File   dir = new File("C:\Documents and Setting\username\temp");
String fn  = "Top 1/2.pdf";
URI    uri = new URI( dir.toURI().toASCIIString() + URLEncoder.encoder( fn, "ASCII" ).toString() );
File   out = new File( uri );

System.out.println( dir.toURI().toASCIIString() );
System.out.println( URLEncoder.encode( fn, "ASCII" ).toString() );
System.out.println( uri.toASCIIString() );
System.out.println( output.toURI().toASCIIString() );
```

The output is:

```
file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/username/temp/
Top+1%2F2.pdf   
file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/username/temp/Top+1%2F2.pdf
file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/username/temp/Top+1/2.pdf
```

After the new File object is instantiated, the `%2F` sequence is automatically converted to a forward slash and I end up with an incorrect path.  Does anybody know the proper way to approach this issue?

The core of the problem seems to be that

```
uri.equals( new File(uri).toURI() ) == FALSE
```

when there is a `%2F` in the URI.

I'm planning to just use the URLEncoded string verbatim rather than trying to use the `File(uri)` constructor.

Comment: It's certainly correct to do so. If you need a verbatim `%2F` in the file name than it must be escaped properly when used in an URI: `%252F`

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  I don't want to encode '%2F', I want to encode '/' so that I can create a legal file name that represents a user-specified name that contains the forward slash.

Comment: Out of interest: I know these are file URIs, but if they were http URIs shouldn't the webserver handle `%F2` and `/` the same? Also: Since `/` is not valid in a windows filename, such a file URI doesn't seem to make sense, or?

Comment: @RoToRa: To the point, he just want the ability to use URLencoded characters in filenames. That doesn't work properly since `new File(URI)` decodes them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`new File(URI)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29) constructs the file based on the path as obtained by [`URI#getPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getPath%28%29) instead of -what you expected- [`URI#getRawPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getRawPath%28%29). This look like a feature "by design".

You have 2 options:

1. Run [`URLEncoder#encode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on `fn` twice (note: `encode()`, not `encoder()`).
2. Use [`new File(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

Comment: Makes sense.  It this documented anywhere, or is it implied by the File class guarantee that "new File(f.toURI()).equals( f.getAbsoluteFile())"?

Comment: @Lucas - it is not documented; see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I think that @BalusC has nailed the direct problem in your code.  I'd just like to point out some other issuse

The `dir.toURI().toASCIIString()` and `URLEncoder.encoder(fn, "UTF-8").toString()` expressions actually do rather different things.

- The first one, encodes the URI as a string, applying the URI encoding rules according to the URI grammar.  So for example, a '/' in the path component will not be encoded but a '/' in the query or fragment components will be encoded as %2F.
- The second one, encodes the `fn` String applying the encoding rules without reference to the content of the string.

The `File(URI)` constructor's mapping from a file URI to a File is [system dependent and undocumented](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)).  I'm a bit surprised that it decodes the `%2F`, but it does what it does, and @BalusC explains why.  The take-away is that it is potentially problematic to use a mechanism ("file:" URIs) that are explicitly system dependent.

Finally, it is wrong to combine those URI component strings like that.  It should be either

```
URI uri = new URI(
        dir.toURI().toString() +
        URLEncoder.encoder(fn, "UTF-8").toString();
```

or

```
URI uri = new URI(
        dir.toURI().toASCIIString() +
        URLEncoder.encoder(fn, "ASCII").toString());
```