# How to pass %2f to java.net.URI without it being turned into /

Tags: java, scala, rabbitmq, url-encoding, scala-dispatch

I'm using Dispatch from Scala as follows:

```
val body = """{"count":5,"requeue":true,"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}"""
val req = url("http://localhost:4567/api/queues/%2f/myQueue/get").as_!("guest", "guest") << (body, "application/json")

val http = new Http

val resp = http(req as_str)
```

The `%2f` gets turned into a `/`, so it tries to post to `/api/queues///myQueue/get` rather than to `/api/queues/%2f/myQueue/get`.

How do I escape this properly?

Comment: Could this be a related issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765782/why-does-java-automatically-decode-2f-in-uri-encoded-filenames

Answer (score 1):

% sign is used in url encoding. So, %2f gets decoded into /. try it on browser and you will see.

Use %25 to represent % sign. e.g.

```
val req = url("http://localhost:4567/api/queues/%252f/myQueue/get")
```

Comment: That gets turned into `/api/queues/%252f/cdm.mio/get` rather than `/api/queues/%2f/cdm.mio/get`  :(

Comment: That's interesting. %2f gets decoded but %25 does not, both being valid.