# How, in Java, to encode default vhost %2F in URL/URI so it doesn't get changed to slash and fail to work

Tags: java, rabbitmq

To use the admin API, the default vhost "/" must be encoded as %2F, per the documentation: [2nd paragraph, here](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html).

I am stuck getting the `java.net.URI` class - as used by most any http-requestish thing (e.g., `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase`) - to emit a string of that form.

I.e., I would like `new URI("http", null, "localhost", 8080, "/api/exchanges/%2F", "", null).toASCIIString()` to be `http://localhost:8080/api/exchanges/%2F?` but it's not, instead it is `http://localhost:8080/api/exchanges/%252F?`.

And if the path is `/api/exchanges//` (double slash, where the second slash is supposed to be the default vhost, which is wrong, but never mind) then the result is `http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges//?` (which doesn't work with the RabbitMQ admin service, which thinks it is `http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/` (one slash), which then returns all exchanges on all vhosts.

So, what's the secret?

(By the way, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765782/why-does-java-automatically-decode-2f-in-uri-encoded-filenames) is not a dupe: it is all about starting from a `File`, which really should have specialized knowledge of "/" in paths.  I'm here just talking about plain-Jane URIs.)

FYI, wall-of-code TestNG tests that show various permutations - these tests all *pass* which shows that I can't get `%2F` out this way:

```
package com.bakins_bits;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestSingleSlashURIPaths
{
    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void does_URI_or_URL_mangle_single_slash_paths_example_1()
        throws MalformedURLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {
        // ARRANGE
        String sut = "http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges//";

        // ACT
        URL url = new URL(sut);
        String path = "/api/exchanges//";
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), path, "", url.getRef());
        String result = uri.toURL().toString();

        // ASSERT
        assertThat(url.toString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges//");
        assertThat(uri.getPath()).isEqualTo("/api/exchanges//");
        assertThat(uri.toString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges//?");
        assertThat(uri.toASCIIString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges//?");
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges//?");
    }

    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void does_URI_or_URL_mangle_single_slash_paths_example_2()
        throws MalformedURLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {
        // ARRANGE
        String sut = "http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%2F";

        // ACT
        URL url = new URL(sut);
        String path = "/api/exchanges/%2F";
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), path, "", url.getRef());
        String result = uri.toURL().toString();

        // ASSERT
        assertThat(url.toString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%2F");
        assertThat(uri.getPath()).isEqualTo("/api/exchanges/%2F");
        assertThat(uri.toString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%252F?");
        assertThat(uri.toASCIIString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%252F?");
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%252F?");
    }

    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void does_URI_or_URL_mangle_single_slash_paths_example_3()
        throws MalformedURLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {
        // ARRANGE
        String sut = "http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%252F";

        // ACT
        URL url = new URL(sut);
        String path = "/api/exchanges/%252F"; // try pre-encoding the '%'
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), path, "", url.getRef());
        String result = uri.toURL().toString();

        // ASSERT
        assertThat(url.toString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%252F");
        assertThat(uri.getPath()).isEqualTo("/api/exchanges/%252F");
        assertThat(uri.toString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%25252F?");
        assertThat(uri.toASCIIString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%25252F?");
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%25252F?");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any documentation.  Do you have a link that doesn't go to your local host?

Comment: @markspace - oops, fixed!

Comment: How do you want to use the `URI` object afterwards in your code?

Comment: @SubOptimal It's passed into some kind of HttpRequest object (apache's, unirest's, or some other library) for a GET call.  The APIs for these objects either take a URI, or take a string which they immediately convert to a URI.  Then they use it internally to make the http call.

Comment: @davidbak Thanks. Only to be sure that it could not be solved in another way, as this wasn't clear to me in the request. Seems you need a not valid URI. Maybe not possible that way.

Comment: `new URL ("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%2F") .toURI()` or just `new URI ("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%2F")` in the first place

Comment: @davidbak The answer from dave_thompson_085 seems to work for you. If you use the constructor with your expected URL as `new URI("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%2F?")` you get your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fascinating.  @dave_thompson_085 and @Suboptimal gave the answer in comments above (not sure how to given them rep credit since those aren't answers).  (I was suffering a bit of tunnel vision and didn't try it myself.)

The problem is apparently in the constructor `URI(String scheme, String userInfo, String host, int port, String path, String query, String fragment)` because the constructor `URI(String str)` works.

Note though that even in that case (see test below) `URI::getPath()` will return not `%2F` you'd expect (because that was your input) but `/`.

Nevertheless I'm happy because it means the problem can be resolved in the client library I'm using (which is using the 7 argument constructor, not the 1 argument constructor).  So I'll file a bug there.  (Unfortunately, the method in that library that has this constructor call is `private static` inside a helper class where it is called (and put in a data structure which is consumed) in another static method so there's no easy/obvious runtime patch I can make (by, e.g., subclassing).  I **hate** utility classes. I'll have to build my own copy of this library to fix it.)

Thanks!

```
    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void does_URI_or_URL_mangle_single_slash_paths_example_4()
        throws MalformedURLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {
        // ARRANGE
        String sut = "http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%2F?";

        // ACT
        URI uri = new URI(sut);
        String result = uri.toURL().toString();

        // ASSERT
        assertThat(uri.getPath()).isEqualTo("/api/exchanges//"); // <== this seems wrong!
        assertThat(uri.toString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%2F?");
        assertThat(uri.toASCIIString()).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8800/api/exchanges/%2F?");
    }
```